# Implicit differentiation 2 questions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hello everyone I have two questions on implicit differentiation.

My first one is express $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ if $x^2-4xy^3+8x^2y=20$

what I did is this

$2x-4x(3y^2)(\frac{dy}{dx})+4y^3+8x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+16xy=0$

$-4x(3y^2\frac{dy}{dx})+8x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=-2x-4y^3-16$

Finally I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-4y^3-16}{-4(x)(3y^2)+8x^2}$

My second question is

Find an equation for the tangent line to the graph of $2x^2-5y^2+xy=5$ at the point $(2,1)$

Anyway I simplified the equation to

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-4x-1}{-10y+x}$ plugging in x and y I got $\frac{9}{8}$

so my line is $y-1=\frac{9}{8}(x-2)$ but I am unsure if if I did this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very well done, Fernando. You indeed found the equation for the line tangent to the second equation at the point $(2, 1)$, and your first solution look like you differentiated properly, too.

You could simplify just a tad: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-4y^3-16}{-4(x)(3y^2)+8x^2} = \frac{2(x-2y^3 - 8)}{4(-3xy^2 +2)} = \frac{x - 2y^3 - 8}{2(-3xy^2 + 2)}$$

Comment: You're welcome, Fernando!

Answer (score 0):

There are slight computation errors and omission errors; Other than that you are doing fine. If you experience such errors, it is better to write every step.

In the first one,
when you differentiate both sides you get $2x-4(x3y^2 dy/dx +y^3)+8(2xy+x^2 dy/dx)=0$. Thus $(-4x3y^2+8x^2)dy/dx=-2x+4y^3-16xy$ so that $dy/dx=\frac{-2x+4y^3-16xy}{-12xy^2+8x^2}=\frac{-x+2y^3-8xy}{-6xy^2+4x^2}$

In the second one, a similar error is there.
Differentiating gives $4x-10y dy/dx+(x dy/dx +y)=0$ and thus $(-10y+x)dy/dx=-4x+y$ so that $dy/dx=\frac{-4x-y}{-10y+x}$. The value you get after substitution is accidentally(?) same here.